PandaCss how to override Css variable?
I have object with css Variable in my componentRecipe1
I import this object to another component2 where i use Component1
How can I override my css varaible?
For example:
export const cssObj = { colorVatiable: '--color' }
In another component i try this:
cssObj.colorVatiable = 'red'

But my style not Override
I try to find in docs how to import object in build time, but dont found

I guess we can try exporting a dedicated method from Component1 that would accept the new property value as an argument and apply it to componentRecipe1, then call this method instead of modifying the property of a new instance, which wouldn't take effect.
However, it's difficult to offer assistance without understanding the component interaction fully. Could you please provide more information?

I have object of css Vars for my Component1:
export const obj = bgColor: '--color_of_bg"
And i  import this object to Component2 which use Component1
I try to override styles in my recipe in Component2:
sva {
comp1{
[obj.bgColor]: 'red'
}
}
and then
const defaultCss = Comp2Recipe.raw ({variant})

if i use
sva {
comp1{
--color_of_bg: 'red'
}
}
It work finally
The import does not take place during the build
Sorry, i cant Undarstand how to use code Section in commentary
